# Using Multiple versions of the same entity framework class using @model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

i have a local SQL db set up just now and i was working on using EF in an MVC website and I'm wondering if anyone could possible shed some light on using models in the View. I seem to have hit a stag in that I need to use multiple version of the same model by querying the database with separate queries. 
(The research seemed to point to LINQ-to-SQL for this)

Anyway
This is the controller class that i have just now

```
public ActionResult Clubs(int comp)
{
var dbContext = new DataDBEntities();
switch (comp)
{
    case 1:
      var query = from clubs in dbContext .Clubs where clubs.League_Table == 1 select clubs;
      var PremList = query.ToList();
      return View(PremList.ToList());
    case 2:
      var query1 = from clubs in dbContext .Clubs where clubs.League_Table == 2 select clubs;
      var Div1List = query1.ToList();
      return View(Div1List.ToList());
    case 3:
      var query2 = from clubs in dbContext .Clubs where clubs.League_Table == 3 select clubs;
      var Div2AList = query2.ToList();
      return View(Div2AList.ToList());
    case 4:
      var Div2BContext = new DataDBEntities();
      var query3 = from clubs in dbContext .Clubs where clubs.League_Table == 4 select clubs;
      var Div2BList = query3.ToList();
      return View(Div2BList.ToList());
    case 5:
      var query4 = from clubs in dbContext .Clubs where clubs.League_Table == 5 select clubs;
      var Div2CList = query4.ToList();
      return View(Div2CList.ToList());
    case 6:
      var query5 = from clubs in dbContext .Clubs where clubs.League_Table == 6 select clubs;
      var Div2DList = query5.ToList();
      return View(Div2DList.ToList());
    default:
      break;    
    }
    return View(db.Clubs.ToList());
}
```

and in the View i am using @model IEnumerable

```
@model IEnumerable<SundayCentralAFL.Models.Club>

@{ 
    ViewBag.title = "Clubs Contacts";
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <section id="bodyWrapper">
        <section id="leftBody">
            <section id="leftAds">

                <section class="ads">
                    <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
                </section>
                <section class="ads">
                    <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
                </section>
            </section>
            <section id="clubList">
                <div id="accordion">
                    <div>
                        <h2>Premier Division</h2>
                        <table class="contactTable">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Club Name</th>
                                <th>Manager Name</th>
                                <th>Contact Details</th>
                            </tr>

                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Club_Name)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manager)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact_Number)</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Division 1</h2>
                        <table class="contactTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Club Name</td>
                                <td>Manager Name</td>
                                <td>Contact Details</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Division 2A</h2>
                        <table class="contactTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Club Name</td>
                                <td>Manager Name</td>
                                <td>Contact Details</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Division 2B</h2>
                        <table class="contactTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Club Name</td>
                                <td>Manager Name</td>
                                <td>Contact Details</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Division 2C</h2>
                        <table class="contactTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Club Name</td>
                                <td>Manager Name</td>
                                <td>Contact Details</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Division 2D</h2>
                        <table class="contactTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Club Name</td>
                                <td>Manager Name</td>
                                <td>Contact Details</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="rightBody">
            <section class="ads">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sundaycentralmedia" alt="Sunday Central AFL" title="Sunday Central AFL" target="_blank"><img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" /></a>
            </section>
            <section class="ads">
                <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
            </section>
            <section class="ads">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sundaycentralmedia" alt="Sunday Central AFL" title="Sunday Central AFL" target="_blank"><img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" /></a>
            </section>
            <section class="ads">
                <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
```

Now, for each of the individual league tables i am hoping to use a foreach loop or just a for loop to populate the tables based on the individual queries. Default will be required to run all 6 queries ad produce the required data for the view if no table/wrong table is assigned in the URL link.

This does appear to be working when using just one query and passing the list to the view but i need all the respected division club lists to be passed and then used at the other end.

I have seen the possibility in using viewModels but the I am unsure of the approach.

Another would be to use partialViews, but would that not run into the same issues as the main view in that I could only pass one overall model with all the clubs and not the individual list of club required.

Any further information needed that could help just ask

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You `Clubs` action can be reduced as I show as follow:

```
public ActionResult Clubs(int comp)
{
  using(var context=new DataDBEntities())
  {
     var query= context.Clubs;
     if(comp!=0)//default value
     { 
        query=query.Where(c=>c.League_Table ==comp);
     }
     return View(query.ToList());
  }
}
```

### Update

Now I saw you need all the leagues. In that case you need to do a group by:

```
var query= context.Clubs.GroupBy(c=>c.League_Table);
```

But you are going to need to change the type of your model to `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Club>>`, and use two cycles in your view, the first one to iterate per each group, and the second one to iterate per each clubs that belong to the current group. Now but there is a problem with this solution, you don't have the league's name with this query. I guess `League_Table` is a FK property in your `Club` entity. If that is the case you should have a `League` navigation property, so you could group by League name instead by Id:

```
var query= context.Clubs.GroupBy(c=>c.League.Name);
```

So, your model type would be in this case `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Club>>`, and you could do something like this inside your accordion:

```
@foreach (var group in Model) 
{
  <div>
     <h2>group.Key</h2>
     <table class="contactTable">
        <tr>
           <th>Club Name</th>
           <th>Manager Name</th>
           <th>Contact Details</th>
        </tr>
           @foreach (var item in group)
            {
              <tr>
                 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Club_Name)</td>
                 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manager)</td>
                 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact_Number)</td>
              </tr>
             }
         </table>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: thanks alot @octavioccl this seems to explain things better. I knew the controller could be improved but didn't know how to best explain the issue. League_Table is used solely as a league indicator for this very reason again thanks for the answer and help its works great after a little change ;)

I had to remove the query=query.where(c=>c.League_Table ==comp); after i put the var query= context.Clubs.GroupBy(c=>c.League_Table); but works now

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the `ViewData.Model` parameter, so the @model diretive doesn't have any data to work with. Also, we can improve your code a little bit:

```
public ActionResult Clubs(int comp)
{
    var dbContext = new DataDBEntities();
    var query = from clubs in dbContext.Clubs where clubs.League_Table == comp select clubs;
    var data = query.ToList();

    if (data.Count == 0) ViewData.Model = dbContext.Clubs.ToList();
    else ViewData.Model = data;

    return View();
}
```